Winter Bash 2019 Winners!
I want to say a big thanks to everyone who participated in Winter Bash this year! We had a total of 170 users earn 367 hats!
We added 200 new users to our community this December, more than in any month since the initial spike when we entered public beta in 2011. We also had more new visits and total page views than we've ever had. Thank you to each of you for keeping the site tidy, active, and welcoming for all of the folks that were interacting with our community for the first time.

Now for the contest results:
We had a tie for most hats between @NeverForget and @AlexanderO'Mara. They've agreed to split the grand prize rather than flipping a coin for it, so they'll each get a set of their choosing up to a 100 EUR value. Congrats to both of our winners!
The following 32 users earned at least 3 hats:
Alexander O'Mara (22 hats)
Never Forget (22 hats)
zovits supports GoFundMonica (18 hats)
Rin Rio-Oki (12 hats)
Phil B. (9 hats)
Ambo100 (8 hats)
Chris says Reinstate Monica (8 hats)
Dan1138 (6 hats)
Ankit Sharma (6 hats)
Eran (6 hats)
jncraton (6 hats)
O. R. Mapper (5 hats)
Henrik - stop hurting Monica (5 hats)
Alex (5 hats)
Joe Slater (5 hats)
technicguy1 (4 hats)
lee (4 hats)
X-27 wants to Reinstate Monica (4 hats)
Zhaph - Ben Duguid (4 hats)
user13489 (4 hats)
Scott (3 hats)
Shootforthemoon (3 hats)
PeterJ (3 hats)
Michael Verschaeve (3 hats)
chicks (3 hats)
Joost (3 hats)
WELZ (3 hats)
Robert Columbia (3 hats)
Tonny (3 hats)
Makyen (3 hats)
SkyPaul (3 hats)
Daron Senior (3 hats)

I've excluded the two grand prize winners and three mods from the drawing as stated in the contest rules. The three randomly selected winners are:

Chris says Reinstate Monica
O. R. Mapper
Ankit Sharma

Congrats to our winners! Each of you will receive a Ginger Bread House:

Winners should email me at my SE username at gmail with shipping information and prize selections. I will be reaching out via other means in the next few days if I don't hear anything from the winners.
Thanks everyone!

Congrats to the winners!

Wow, I really won \o/

Wow, that's amazing! I just got back into LEGO (after about 20 years) a few months ago and the Gingerbread House seems really nice, I'm super happy!

This year's Winter Bash was a Smash!

Congratulations to the winners and a happy new year for everybody :)

Thanks and I just wanted to confirm that I received it last week.

@AnkitSharma Great! I hope that you've enjoyed it!

I know it can take a while, but should I be concerned that I have not yet received it?

@AlexanderO'Mara I'm sorry to hear that this hasn't arrived. The lead times are very long after the holidays as you know. There may also be an impact from Coronavirus at this point due to shipping and supply chain delays. The Billund warehouse is closed for at least the next two weeks for example. I've asked for an update from TLG, but I'm not anticipating a quick response with everything else going on.

Well it arrived today after all.

@AlexanderO'Mara Wow. Sorry about the delay. I hope that you are enjoying it! Congrats again!

Thanks! I know it's not your fault.
